# nginx proxy_pass application with prefix

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I need to serve multiple instances of same application for different users.
Say I have users as user1, user2 and user3. My nginx.conf will be like below.

```
server {    
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /user1/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
    }

    location /user2/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp2;
    }

    location /user3/ {
        proxy_pass http://myapp3;
    }
}
```

The application will redirect user back and forth several times. The userX prefix is lost at first proxy pass and next calls are sent to /.

I am using nginx inside a docker container and already read and tried below.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: On browser I navigate to http://localhost/user1/.
Then it is redirected to http://localhost/login.
What I need to happen is redirecting to http://localhost/user1/login.

Answer (score 0):

I simply followed a workaround as below to get done what I needed.

```
upstream user1 {
    server myapp1;
}
upstream user2 {
    server myapp2;
}
upstream user3 {
    server myapp3;
}
server {    
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        //Used a lua script to identify the user
        proxy_pass http://$userX;
    }
}
```